# Django: Difference between BASE_DIR and PROJECT_ROOT?

Tags: python, django

From settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: `PROJECT_ROOT` is the folder that contains `setting.py` and `BASE_DIR` contains `PROJECT_ROOT`...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They're almost the same thing. `BASE_DIR` is where your `manage.py` lies, and `PROJECT_ROOT` is `BASE_DIR` + *your_project_name* (where `settings.py` is).

Comment: Is there anywhere in the documentation that explains the definition for the variables? I tried Googling and I couldn't find it. I also tried the official django source code global_settings.py and couldn't find it there either: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/conf/global_settings.py